# Is the apostrophe mark named after the rhetorical device or vice versa?

Tags: punctuation, rhetorical-devices

As far as I can tell, without getting into the possessive apostrophe, they have related functions: The apostrophe mark denotes a missing character (or series of characters) in the contraction of a word or phrase and the rhetorical device represents turning away from addressing the audience and addressing someone or something that is (usually) not present.

I realise this is potentially a chicken vs egg question but recently I found myself wondering this: Assuming they *are* related, which came first or which was named after which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figurative  meaning of "turning  away"  came first, from which the mark showing  where a letter has been omitted:

***[apostrophe (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=apostrophe)***:

> - mark indicating omitted letter, 1580s, ***from Middle French apostrophe, from Late Latin apostrophus, from Greek apostrophos (prosoidia) "(the accent of) turning away," thus, a mark showing where a letter has been omitted, from apostrephein "avert, turn away,"*** from apo- "from" (see apo-) + strephein "to turn" (see strophe).
> - In English, the mark often represents loss of -e- in -es, possessive ending. It was being extended to all possessives, whether they ever had an -e- or not, by 18c. ***Greek also used this word for a "turning aside" of an orator in speech to address some individual, a sense first recorded in English 1530s.***

(Etymonline)

Comment: Thanks. I am aware they share broadly the same etymology in that 'apostrophe' means 'turning away', but I was really interested in the relationship between the rhetorical device and the mark. Judging from your references, it looks like it's impossible to guess which gave its name to which.

Comment: @AndrewMartin -         As you can see from the extract above, the rethorical figure was used in English at least five decades before the orthographic sense.